# How to find partial derivative of a function with respect to a seperate vector of weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, derivative

I have a Generative adversarial network. I have considered the Generator as Neural network 1 (N1) and the discriminator as the neural network 2 (N2). The loss function of the generator is L1 and the discriminator is L2. I want to train the GAN in a specific way. For that, I need to calculate a Jacobian matrix which will contain the following:-

D=Jacobian matrix=

partial derivate of L1 wrt weights of N1, partial derivate of L1 wrt weights of N2
partial derivate of L2 wrt weights of N1, partial derivate of L2 wrt weights of N2

Comment: Please detail your question, although the question you are asking is already a solved one.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar - I have tried to elucidate the problem above.